# Can I move data from my test iPad to my development environment

Tags: ios

I'm developing an iPad app that involves drawing. How can I move example data created on my test iPad into my development environment so I can include examples with the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode allows you to import the data your app creates on the device onto your mac:

Connect your iPad to your mac.

In Xcode go to Windows/Devices (shift-cmd-2)
and you'll see a list of apps on your iPad (you may have to select your device first)

select your drawing app, click on the settings icon near the bottom and import the contents of the app to your mac.

Right click on the folder (in Finder), and select inspect/open/reveal contents and navigate to your data.

I don't have an iPad connected right now, but let me know if you get stuck, and I can be more specific.

Comment: Thanks very much! Worked perfectly.

Comment: awesome! so glad. 